# Decoding JSON into model using MVVM

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am unable to decode my JSON data into my model. This is my first time attempting to use MVVM pattern and for some reason I cannot figure out why I cannot get a reference to my model variables such as title or id. Besides the error shown below I also get a message saying 'This property is defined on Movie and may not be available in this context'

```
class MovieViewModel {
    
    let movie: APIResponse
    
    init(movie: APIResponse) {
        self.movie = movie
    }
    
    var title: String {
        return movie.data.title // Value of type [Movie] has no member 'title'
    }
    
         }
     
       struct APIResponse: Codable {
          var data: [Movie]
     }

       struct Movie: Codable {
           var id: String
           var title: String
  
    
       }

      class MovieListViewModel {
    
    
    
    private var movieViewModels = [MovieViewModel]()
    
    func addMovieViewModels(_ vm: MovieViewModel) {
        movieViewModels.append(vm)
    }
    
    func numberOfRows(_ section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return movieViewModels.count
    }


    func modelAtIndex(_ Index: Int) -> GiphyViewModel {
        
        return movieViewModels[Index]
    }

}
```

Comment: Because `movie.data` is an `Array`, so there could be multiple `Movies` in `data`, so when you do which `title` do you expect? And your naming is confusing. In `MovieViewModel`, `movie` is a `APIResponse`, not a `Movie`.

Comment: @Larme I am attempting to set them as the title for the specific row in a table view.

Comment: You need to rethink the way you're doing this. Your class `MovieViewModel` is a video store that contains multiple movies. Someone walks in and says "What's the title of the movie?". You would need the position in that array, to reference a specific movie, then extract its title.

Comment: You probably want one view model that holds all movies and one view model that holds a single movie.

Comment: Try the following. var title: String {
        return movie.data.first.title
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think you should seperate API calls from the view model.
You can take example on this [repo](https://github.com/Tooflex/arbres) to know how to proceed.

Comment: The call isn't part of the class. `APIResponse` is just an array of `Movie`. He could've called it `Movies`.